Filling a Tkinter Canvas. Whats the easiest way to fill figure, which composed with different base shapes and images?
I'm creating a figure from several primitive shapes, what is the easiest way for me to paint them all at the same time?
Its how i create the figure:
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
c=Canvas(root,width=700,height=500,bg='blue',cursor="pencil")
c.create_arc(300,200,250,175,outline='white',style=ARC,start=0,extent=180)#1
c.create_arc(250,200,200,175,outline='white',style=ARC,start=0,extent=180)#2
c.create_arc(200,200,150,175,outline='white',style=ARC,start=0,extent=180)#3
c.create_arc(150,200,100,175,outline='white',style=ARC,start=0,extent=180)#4
c.create_arc(100,100,300,270,outline='white',style=ARC,start=0,extent=180)#umbrella
c.create_line(200,185,200,300,fill='white')
c.create_arc(200,325,250,275,outline='white',style=ARC,start=180,extent=180)
c.pack()
root.mainloop()

I'm trying to find an analogue of the FloodFill command (from Pascal), but I couldn't
I would be very grateful for your help

The Canvas can only apply colors to a single object - your multiple separate drawing objects do not define anything that can be colored.  You need to somehow combine all of the lines that define your colored area into a single object, perhaps a polygon (using smooth=True so that you can have curves).  "Flood fill" is a concept that only applies to raster drawing, but a Canvas is purely vector drawing.

You can group canvas objects together using tags.
This can be used to collectively change fill, outline and other properties as well as group control of movement and scale.
NOTE:
canvas line only uses fill and not outline so for a single line try using polygon.
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

c=Canvas(root,width=700,height=500,bg='blue',cursor="pencil")
c.pack()

# polygon instead of line
c.create_polygon(200,185,200,300, tags="hue")
c.create_arc(200,325,250,275, style=ARC, tags="hue", start=180, extent=180)
c.create_arc(300,200,250,175, style=ARC, tags = "hue", start=0, extent=180)#1
c.create_arc(250,200,200,175, style=ARC, tags = "hue", start=0, extent=180)#2
c.create_arc(200,200,150,175, style=ARC, tags = "hue", start=0, extent=180)#3
c.create_arc(150,200,100,175, style=ARC, tags = "hue", start=0, extent=180)#4
c.create_arc(100,100,300,270, style=ARC, tags = "hue", start=0, extent=180)#umbrella

# Color and change properties of all objects in one statement using tags
c.itemconfig("hue", fill="orange", outline="yellow", width=4)

root.mainloop()

